# Finding number of injections $A \to A$.

Tags: functions, solution-verification, proof-writing

I believe I've been able to solve this problem without issue, but I'm most concerned with precision and the rigor of my argument. The problem is:

> Let $A$ be a finite set, $|A| = n > 0$. How many functions $f: A \to A$ are there?
> How many of these are injective?

Here is what I came up.

> (a) Let $A = \{a_1, \ldots,a_n\}$. Then, there are $n$ possibilities for the image of $a_1$ under $f$. For each of these $n$ possibilities, there are $n$ possibilities for the image of $a_2$. Furthermore, for each $i > 1$, there are $n$ possibilities for the image of $a_i$ given the $n^{i-1}$ options for where $f$ sent $a_1, \ldots, a_{i-1}$. Therefore, there are $|A|^{|A|} = n^n$ total functions $f: A \to A$.
>
> (b) We enumerate the elements of $A$ as above. There are then $n$ possibilities for where $f$ maps $a_1$. For each of these $n$ possibilities, there are then $n-1$ possibilities for where $f$ maps $a_2$; indeed, as $a_1 \neq a_2$, we must have $f(a_1) \neq f(a_2)$ since $f$ must be injective. Then, for each $i > 1$, we must have $f(a_i) \neq f(a_{i-1}) \neq \ldots \neq f(a_1)$. Therefore, having assigned $i-1$ elements of $A$, there are $n-i$ remaining possibilities for where $f$ assigns $a_i$ for each of these $n \cdot (n-1) \cdots (n-(i-2))$ possibilities for where $f$ assigned $a_1, \ldots, a_{i-1}$. Therefore, there are exactly $n!$ such injections $f: A \to A$.

How does this look?

Comment: For a function, there's also the possibility that an element has no image.

Comment: @Raskolnikov My understanding is that the defining characteristic of a function is that every element of the domain possesses a unique image.

Comment: Since $f$ is a function, it could also be the zero function or, a function that takes at least one (or more) elements to zero. Your current argument in $(a)$ makes $f$ surjective since you are assuming there are $n$ possibilities for the image of every element.

Comment: @sadman-ncc I'm not sure I understand. I'm trying to account for all possible functions $A \to A$, which includes surjections. Doesn't that also account for the possibility that I chose the same element $n$ times?

Comment: What you did here is only include surjections (right?). But there are other possibilities (mentioned in my last comment) that you still need to count for as Raskolnikov also mentioned.

Comment: I am very confused by these comments - your arguments look fine. If an element in the domain has no image in the codomain then you have a partial function, which is a different beast entirely. And nowhere in your proof do you state what kind of set $A$ is other than being finite, but regardless if an element does map to zero then that would mean that $a_i = 0$ for some $i$.

Comment: To judge your proof it's important to know your level of knowing mathematics. If you don't know mathematical induction, your proof is more or less perfect. If you know induction, it's better to use it to be more precise.

Comment: @Mateo I do know induction, though I didn't think of using it. I could try to define a function by induction, e.g., define $f(1)$ and for $i > 1$, define $f(i)$ having defined $f(1), \ldots, f(i-1)$. This makes sense for (b) since there's a dependence on the image of the predecessor elements, but I can't think of a way to do (a) with induction.

Comment: @Cardinality, you can prove by induction on $n$ that if the set has $n$ elements then there are $n!$ injections.

Comment: @Mateo Ok, so how about this. When $n = 1$, there is only one $(=1!)$ function $A \to A$, which is certainly injective. We suppose inductively that for any $k$-element set, there are exactly $k!$ injections from the set to itself. Then let $A = \{a_1, \ldots, a_{k+1}\}$. For each $i$, we define $A_i := A \setminus \{a_i\}$, each of which has $k$ elements. By the inductive assumption, there are exactly $k!$ functions from $A_i$ to $A_i$. To extend each function $A_i \to A_i$ to a function from $A$ to $A$, we have to have assign $a_i$, and there is only one option left, i.e., $f(a_i) = a_i$.

Comment: The proof looks incorrect since there's no reason I should be required to fix $a_i$, but it's the only element left.

Comment: You should first define $f(a_{k+1})=a_j$ and you can do it on $k+1$ ways. Then you can extend this function by using $g\colon\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}\to\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{k+1}\}\setminus\{a_j\}$, which you can do on $k!$ ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following proof is IMV rigorous enough:

> (a) Let $A = \{a_1, \ldots,a_n\}$. Then for every $i$ there are $n$ possibilities for the image of $a_i$ under $f$. Therefore, there are $n^n$ functions $f: A \to A$.
>
> (b) We enumerate the elements of $A$ as above. There are then $n$ possibilities for $f(a_1)$. Then there are $n-1$ possibilities for $f(a_2)$ because the injectivity demands that $f(a_2)\neq f(a_1)$. Repeating this we find $n-i+1$ possibilities for $f(a_i)$ and conclude that there are exactly $n!$ injections $f: A \to A$.

As you can see it is your proof just writing things a bit more concisely.

I don't think there are math teachers who will put this aside with: "...not rigorous enough.."

At least I am not one of them.

Yes, induction on $n$ can be applied, but that does not make the proof above less rigorous.